# Schedule a javascript future call and cancel any pending calls

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to do an expensive API call scheduled 5 minutes in the future triggered on a user changing parameters. If the user changes parameters again 10 seconds later I DO NOT want a call in 4m50s AND a call in 5m, I want to essentially cancel the call in 4m50s since it's moot.

I've found debounce in lodash which enforces a minimum time before calls but it won't cancel any pending but not executed calls so while it prevents rapid calls it still does an unnecessary call so is now quite it. Any clean ideas to do this?

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `debounce` documentation:

> The debounced function comes with a `cancel` method to cancel delayed func invocations

So just ensure that you call `method.cancel` before re-invoking `method` with the altered parameters:

```
var debounced = _.debounce(api_func, 5 * 60 * 1000, { trailing: true });
```

and in the trigger handler (which must have the above variable `debounced` accessible in its scope):

```
debounced.cancel();
debounced( params );
```

---

Alternatively, just use the built-in timer functions, where the solution should trivially be:

```
var timer;
```

and in the trigger:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
timer = setTimeout(api_func, 5 * 6 * 1000);
```

Comment: @ss2k which of the above two methods did you use?

Comment: I already had a dependency on lodash so went with the debounce.